# Can you convert an array of Bytes to an array of Strings and then back to an array of Bytes?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have an array of Bytes

```
val base = [-2, 50, 48]
```

and I converted this array of Bytes to an array of Strings

```
val baseConverted = ["-2","50","48"]
```

Is there a way to convert 'baseConverted' back to 'base'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `toByte` from a `String` on every element:

```
List("-2","50","48").map(_.toByte)
```

Comment: So simple yet I got stuck on that for over a week. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one can do it using `Array`:

```scala
val baseConverted = Array("-2", "50", "48")

val backToBase = baseConverted.map(_.toByte) 

// Prints
// backToBase: Array[Byte] = Array(-2, 50, 48)
```